# PermissionError when installing statsmodels in virtualenv in Python

Tags: python

I am using Ubuntu and I tried

```
python3 -m virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

where my `requirements.txt` simply consists of

```
numpy
statmodels
```

but I get this error

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

If I try `jupyter notebook` and then type `import numpy as np` in the notebook, I get

```
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not installing the package into the virtual environment.

I guess you're on Linux and using the default pip3 package manager instead of the one included in your virtual environment.

Can you try `pip install -r requirements.txt` and see how it works?

Comment: that worked. Why would it work with `pip` but not `pip3`?

Comment: Because when the virtual environment is created, the default name for the pip package manager binary is pip. pip3 is used system-wise to distinguish with the pip installation of python2 which is probably installed by default on your Linux distribution.

(could you please accept my answer if it solved your problem? thanks)